How to Apply ClassBreaksRenderer in ExportImage for ArcGIS Sentinel-2 NDVI Layer?
I'm working with the ArcGIS JS SDK and using the Sentinel-2 Imagery Layer to display NDVI values. Here's the code I use to apply the ImageryLayer and ClassBreaksRenderer:
this.instance = new ImageryLayer({
   id: this.id,
   url: "https://sentinel.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Sentinel2/ImageServer",
   title: "NDVI",
   rasterFunction: {
      functionName: "NDVI",
      functionArguments: {
         visibleBandID: 4,
         infraredBandID: 8,
         scientificOutput: true // -1 to 1 range
      }
   }
});

let renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer();

ndviRangesValues.forEach(rangeValue => {
  renderer.addClassBreakInfo({
    minValue: rangeValue.range.minValue,
    maxValue: rangeValue.range.maxValue,
    symbol: {
      type: "simple-fill",
      color: rangeValue.hexadecimal,
      outline: { color: [255, 255, 255], width: 1 }
    }
 });
});

This setup works well for displaying NDVI values with custom colors on the map. Now, I need to download the imagery using another date. To do this, I’m using the exportImage endpoint:
https://sentinel.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Sentinel2/ImageServer/exportImage
However, I'm having trouble finding a renderingRule equivalent to the ClassBreaksRenderer I’ve set up for the map. I’ve gone through the raster function documentation but can’t seem to identify how to apply the same color breaks when exporting the image.
Is there a way to achieve this? How can I replicate the ClassBreaksRenderer styling in the exportImage request?
